# How to obtain OAuth access tokens in a public javascript application with no logged in user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2

I'm developing a JavaScript application that needs to interact with an API that's protected with OAuth. However, there users of this JavaScript application don't have accounts anywhere - they are anonymous visitors to a public website. The data in the API results in public, but it's still being protected by OAuth2.

[I examined all the available grant types at my disposal](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Token+API) and none of them really make sense in this scenario.

The "implict" grant type seems appropriate for use in JavaScript applications, but it also assumes that the visitor to the site is a resource owner and the process to obtain the token requires them to "approve" access to the resources. That wouldn't work, because there's no user account that they'd be logging into on the identity server.

I believe my options are:

1. Output the client ID and secret directly into the page, and have
   JavaScript use the client_credentials grant type to obtain a token.
   Obviously anyone could scrape this and use it outside the
   application... but it's public data anyway
2. Have the web server obtain a new token for each visitor to the page
   via the client_credentials grant type. Once it obtains the token, it
   dumps it into the page body so that the JavaScript app can use it
   when making API requests. This hides the client ID and secret from
   JavaScript, but it forces the web server to serve as a seemingly
   pointless middleware for accessing the API. Someone could also just
   scrape the token from the page... but it's public data anyway.
3. Remove OAuth protection from the endpoints entirely (not sure if
   this is even feasible with WSO2 API Manager). It's public data.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove OAuth protection from the endpoints entirely (not sure if this is even feasible with WSO2 API Manager). It's public data.

Yes, for public access this is completely feasible option. You can configure no authorization for resources of API and no OAuth token will be required. As a downside - you won't get any statistics of it.

> Output the client ID and secret directly into the page.. but it's public data anyway

If the credentials are not used used for any other application (resp. non-public access), it should be ok. What you can even do is create a permanent access token (with validity -1). Indeed using this option you may consider the client credentials public.

> Have the web server obtain a new token for each visitor to the page via the client_credentials grant type.

Having the same application the WSO2 APIM will return the same token for the same application while the token is not expired. Though technically this is the right approach when having OAuth authorized data with client credentials.

Comment: "Having the same application the WSO2 APIM will return the same token for the same application while the token is not expired." - In my testing this is not true. When I make consecutive requests for new access tokens, I get a new one each time. The old ones also appear valid while this occurs.